# nodeJS: can't get crypto module to give me the right AES cipher outcome

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to use the nodeJS crypto module to encrypt some hex strings using the ECB mode of AES 128.

To do so, I'm using the following code:

```
cryptoAES = function (sInput, sKey, bEncrypt) {
    return crypto('AES-128-ECB', sInput, sKey, bEncrypt);
};

crypto = function (sAlgo, sInput, sKey, bEncrypt) {
    var result = "";
    if (bEncrypt){
        var cipher;
        var bKey = new Buffer(sKey, 'hex');
        var bInput = new Buffer(sInput, 'hex');

        cipher = crypto.createCipher(sAlgo, bKey);

        cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
        result = cipher.update(bInput, null, 'hex');
        result += cipher.final('hex');
    }
    return result;
};
```

When calling cryptoAES with:

```
sKey = '12345678900987654321123456789001'

sInput = '060123456789ABCDEF00000000000000'
```

I should get

```
result = 'FBECD5D02C5B7CD1055AAF86238D1E2F'
```

but I'm getting:

```
result = 'ea1f940da8e269b9e075c936bff6a1f7'
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you remove the IV from the equation? ECB does not use an IV anyway.

Comment: Indeed, removed iv. But the result doesn't change because the IV wasn't used.

Comment: For other readers, I verified the expected result...

Comment: Thanks for checking. This is already an interesting confirmation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1318#issuecomment-1562766, you *do* need `crypto.createCipheriv()`:

```
cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(sAlgo, bKey, '');
```

That generates the required result.

Comment: This is it. Problem solved.
This is so not logical that the documentation should mention it.

Comment: It seems that the ceateCipher with two parameters uses the algorithm and *password* instead of algorithm and *key*.

Comment: Indeed, and, even if the documentation isn't wrong, I didn't get that immediately.

Comment: This solution is deprecated. If you give empty IV, it will say 'invalid iv length'